# A timer that restarts on a trigger Python - how to restart?

Tags: python, while-loop, timer, triggers, interrupt

Bit of a newbie so bear with:

I am trying to make a crude 60s timer that is reset and starts again on the rising edge of a trigger (ie when a gate goes high). The problem I have is that it won't reset and restart unless the timer has completed (ie reached zero). How do I interrupt the while loop and get it to start again?

Here is my code:

```
import keyboard
import time

t=60

last = False
current = False

while True:
    current = keyboard.is_pressed('space') # triggered when space bar is pressed
    if last == 0 and current == 1: 
        while t>=0:
            print(t)
            t-=1
            time.sleep(1)
    last = current # reset
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion. The problem is, that time.sleep is blocking, so when it's sleeping you cannot break it by pressing escape. You will have to spam the escape button, but it works.

```
import keyboard
import time

t=60

last = False
current = False

while True:
    current = keyboard.is_pressed('space') # triggered when space bar is pressed
    if last == 0 and current == 1: 
        while t>=0:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('escape'):
                t = 60
                last = False
                current = False
                print("Timer stopped.")
                break
            print(t)
            t-=1
            time.sleep(1)
    last = current # reset
```

Sample output/test:

```
60
59
58
57
56
60
59
58
57
56
60
59
60
59
58
```

Comment: This works, but using `break` is avoidable here, by checking current in the inner loop condition instead.

Comment: @7evy You should make an answer yourself and post it. :)

Comment: Right, I'll tweak yours a bit then

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import time
import keyboard
x=60
while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
            x=60
            print(f"Timer reset to {x}")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
            break
        else:
            print(f"{x} seconds left")
            time.sleep(1)
            x-=1
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Comment: You are missing a `:` after your elif statement.

Comment: @user56700 Thanks. It got misplaced while editing the code

Comment: `if keyboard.is_pressed('space') ... elif keyboard.is_pressed('space')` ? I don't think this is necessary? Especially since the use of `break` can be avoided

Comment: What is the purpose of the try and exept?

Comment: @noahch, it is to catch errors if any of them occur

Answer (score 1):

To suggest a solution without `break`:

```
import keyboard
import time

last = 0
current = 0

while True:
    t=60
    current = keyboard.is_pressed('space') # triggered when space bar is pressed
    if last == 0 and current == 1:
        current = 0
        while t>=0 and current == 0:
            print(t)
            t-=1
            time.sleep(1)
            current = keyboard.is_pressed('space')
    last = current # reset
```

Not sure how you want to manage long presses here. If the spacebar stays pressed for more than one second, the timer will reset several times in (technically) one keypress.

Comment: You forgot last. `NameError: name 'last' is not defined`

Comment: Right, I'd removed it at some point, thank you